# Error al importar datos utilizando yahoo finance

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

Para importar las cotizaciones de varios tickers, desde Yahoo Finance, utilizo el script siguiente.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

tickers = ['AAPL', 'GOOG', 'SPY']
tickersAdjClose = pd.DataFrame()
for a in tickers:
    tickersAdjClose[a] = yf.download(a, start= '2016-1-4', progress = False)['Adj Close']
    
tickersAdjClose[:3]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde vemos que ha reconocido que la columna 'Adj Close', se encuentra en el DataFrame creado 'df'.

Intento hacer lo mismo de esta forma muy parecida.

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

tickers = ['AAPL', 'GOOG', 'SPY']

df_list = []
for a in tickers:
    df = yf.download(a, start= '2016-1-4', end = '2022-12-1', auto_adjust=True, 
                     progress = False)
    df_list.append(df['Adj Close'])
    
tickersAdjClose = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)
tickersAdjClose.columns = tickers

tickersAdjClose[:3]
```

Me devuelve el error siguiente:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3652, in Index.get_loc(self, key)
   3651 try:
-> 3652     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3653 except KeyError as err:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:147, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:176, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:7080, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi:7088, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Adj Close'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[33], line 10
      7 for a in tickers:
      8     df = yf.download(a, start= '2016-1-4', end = '2022-12-1', auto_adjust=True, 
      9                      progress = False)
---> 10     df_list.append(df['Adj Close'])
     12 tickersAdjClose = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)
     13 tickersAdjClose.columns = tickers

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3761, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3759 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3760     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3761 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3762 if is_integer(indexer):
   3763     indexer = [indexer]

File ~/anaconda3/envs/yfinance/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3654, in Index.get_loc(self, key)
   3652     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3653 except KeyError as err:
-> 3654     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3655 except TypeError:
   3656     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3657     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3658     #  the TypeError.
   3659     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 'Adj Close'
```

¿Cuál puede ser la causa de este error?. Agradeceré ayudda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

En primer lugar, la función [`download()`](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/wiki/Tickers#download) ya regresa un `dataframe`, por lo que no es necesario crear un `dataframe` nuevo, puedes utilizar directamente el resultado de `download()`.

Si imprimes la información de las dos líneas donde estas descargando los datos de los índices:

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

print(yf.download('AAPL', start= '2016-1-4', progress = False).info())
print(yf.download('AAPL', start= '2016-1-4', end = '2022-12-1', auto_adjust=True, progress = False).info())
```

Puedes ver lo siguiente:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1877 entries, 2016-01-04 to 2023-06-16
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------     --------------  -----  
 0   Open       1877 non-null   float64
 1   High       1877 non-null   float64
 2   Low        1877 non-null   float64
 3   Close      1877 non-null   float64
 4   Adj Close  1877 non-null   float64
 5   Volume     1877 non-null   int64  
dtypes: float64(5), int64(1)
memory usage: 102.6 KB
None
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 1741 entries, 2016-01-04 to 2022-11-30
Data columns (total 5 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------  --------------  -----  
 0   Open    1741 non-null   float64
 1   High    1741 non-null   float64
 2   Low     1741 non-null   float64
 3   Close   1741 non-null   float64
 4   Volume  1741 non-null   int64  
dtypes: float64(4), int64(1)
memory usage: 81.6 KB
None
```

El argumento `auto_adjust`, como su nombre lo indica, realiza un auto ajuste y por lo tanto la columna "Adj Close" desaparece del `dataframe` resultante.

En otras palabras, las dos líneas que estas comparando en tu pregunta hacen cosas diferentes debido al argumento `auto_adjust`.

Te recomiendo revisar la documentación.